# Расположить элементы "listview" в строку

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

Задача в следующем: 
в `listview` сделать список запущенных процессов как в диспетчере задач, в общем должно быть так: иконка процесса, затем его название, на следующей строке тоже самое только следующий просцесс, я использую такой тестовый код:

```
imgList->Images->Add(System::Drawing::Icon::ExtractAssociatedIcon(System::Diagnostics::Process::GetCurrentProcess()->MainModule->FileName));

listView1->LargeImageList = imgList;
listView1->SmallImageList = imgList;

listView1->Items->Add("myProcess", 0);
```

Вывожу для примера название моего процесса и его иконку, выводится вот что: иконка, а под ней названием процесса, что мне нужно изменить - нужно чтобы была иконка, а текст с названием процесса правее и чтобы следующий элемент располагался на следующей строке, а не правее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кому интересно - делается так:

```
listView1->View = View::Details;
```